# In rspec can we turn off verify_partial_doubles for one test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking

My project has this value set in the rspec_helper.rb file

```
mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
```

I have a test that is getting flagged

```
TaskPublisher does not implement #publish
```

The problem is that the method doesn't exist on the object until it's instantiated.  It's a module import based on the the type of task to be published.  (meta programming)

So I'm wondering if there is a way to turn off `verify_partial_doubles` for a specific test, but not affect the other tests that do have the value.

Side question:  Doesn't having this flag set to true make BDD impossible?  It seems to me it flies in the face of Mocking as it's defined(https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mocking/info).

Answer (score 28):

> [Is there] a way to turn off [verify_partial_doubles] for a specific test .. ?

**RSpec >= 3.6**

Use `without_partial_double_verification`

```
it 'example' do
  without_partial_double_verification do
    # ...
  end
end
```

http://rspec.info/blog/2017/05/rspec-3-6-has-been-released/

**RSpec < 3.6**

Yes, with [user-defined metadata](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/metadata/user-defined-metadata) and a [global "around hook"](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/hooks/around-hooks#define-a-global-%60around%60-hook):

```
# In your spec ..
describe "foo", verify_stubs: false do
  # ...
end

# In spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.around(:each, verify_stubs: false) do |ex|
    config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
      mocks.verify_partial_doubles = false
      ex.run
      mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
    end
  end
end
```

I believe credit for this technique goes to [Nicholas Rutherford](https://github.com/nruth), from his post in [rspec-rails issue #1076](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1076).

Answer (score 3):

We encountered a similar problem recently, and ended up going with this:

```
config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
  mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true

  config.around(:example, :without_verify_partial_doubles) do |example|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = false
    example.call
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

Very similar to Jared Beck's answer, but avoiding a second call to `mock_with`.